# Php check box array session

Tags: php

I am new to Php. I got a checkbox array and button(they are not `<form>`). Once the checkbox have checked and the user click the button. It will update the value of the session. Which display how many checkbox it clicked. My problem is the code is not really working.

It is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$add = 0;
$_SESSION["add"] = $add;
if(isset($_POST['checker']) && (isset($_POST['click']))){
    if (is_array($_POST['checker'])){
        foreach ($_POST['checker'] as $value) {
            echo $value;
            $add++;
        }
    }

 echo "<b>You have clicked".$add." box.</b>";
 echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checker[]' value=''/></td></tr>";
}
```

P.S I use mysql to retrieve the row count into the table so there will be 10 checkbox appear.

Comment: In the last part, it should be: echo
"<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='checker[]' value=''/></td></tr>
}" ;

Comment: The name of the checkbox is `checker` but you have used `checkName` in the loop. Please check it.

Comment: Sorry i have made a mistake I updated

Comment: you using a form of relying on something else to iterate over the POST arrays? you also mention mysql; how is that relevant?

Comment: imo, Have a different value attribute in each checkbox so that you can test which are set, and which not, depending on the values in the `$_POST['checker']` array. i.e. `name='checker[]' value='1'` then `name='checker[]' value='2'` in the next checkbox. etc. Remember, only checked values are returned in `$_POST[checker]`. So, the ones that aren't in $_POST['checker'] must be unset.

Comment: *"they are not <form>"* - you need a form for this with a POST method; question's too unclear as to how you're relying on POST arrays being populated. The code looks incomplete with no `<table></table>` tags neither. Nor do we know what `click` is.

Comment: well I'm not going to stay in this question any much longer. The question makes no sense and is missing code.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on button what happens? You have to use javaScript to capture the button click event or if the php code is in same file use this     `<form action="#">` it will load again and check if the $_POST['checker'] isset.

Comment: not my downvote here, but `<form action="#">` without a POST method defaults to GET and they're using POST arrays.

Comment: common sence @Fred-ii- if he is using post he has to define the method post. no need to mention it.

Comment: the question is too unclear and is missing code. I have left the question. WIshing you well with this Salman.